# TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'Caption'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So I have 2 .py files:

1. FW_Engine.py
2. test.py

In FW_Engine.py, I have this code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Display:

  def __init__(self, window, button):
      self.window = window
      self.button = button

  def Window(self, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, Caption):
      GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((WindowWidth, WindowHeight))
      pygame.display.set_caption(Caption)


  def Button(self, DisplayWindow, Position_X, Position_Y):
      GreyColor = (96, 96, 96)
      pygame.draw.rect(DisplayWindow, GreyColor, (Position_X, Position_Y, 100, 20))
```

And on test.py, I have this code:

```
from FW_Engine import Display
import pygame

pygame.init()

GameDisplay = Display.Window(800, 600, "TestTitle")
```

I keep getting this error tho:

```
TypeError: Window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Caption'
```

But as you can see, I have all 3 required arguments supplied into the function call. What's the problem?

EDIT: BOTH .py files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to call `Display.Window` as if it were a static method (ie does not need an instance), but it is not. Since it requires an instance, one argument is missing (the 3 arguments that you provided are shifted left, ie `self` is `800`, etc) hence `Caption` is not provided as the error suggests.

You have 2 options:

1. Call `Window` from a `Display` instance:

   ```
   Display(window, button).Window(800, 600, "TestTitle")
   ```

   Another, less preferable way, would be to pass a `Display` instance to 
   `Display.Window`:

   ```
   display = Display(window, button)
   Display.Window(display, 800, 600, "TestTitle")
   ```
2. Since `Display.Window` does not reference `self` at all, it can be a static method, then the rest of your code will work as-is:

   ```
   class Display:
       def __init__(self, window, button):
           self.window = window
           self.button = button

      @staticmethod
      def Window(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, Caption):
          GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((WindowWidth, WindowHeight))
          pygame.display.set_caption(Caption)
   ```

Comment: To me, the second way seems more readable. Any pros/cons between them?

Comment: @KitsuneMakoto No. The first is actually a syntactic sugar for the second. BTW see the update answer that shows how to use `staticmethod` properly.

Comment: Will mark as accepted answer, staticmethod example solved my issue and helped me understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Window method is not a static method, it's a instance method, so you can not call it without instantiating **Display** object.

The first argument of Window method is **self** which should reference to the object you create, for this case it is **Display** object.

But actually you don't instantiate it, so when you call Window method, you lack the self argument, that's why you see the TypeError.

Try to use it as below, call Window method after creating Display object.

```
GameDisplay = Display(window, button).Window(800, 600, "TestTitle")
```